# PHP how to generate charts from mysql data (google charts)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a report using GOOGLE Chart. I tried a lot of option but It still not working. How do I generate the report with a proper result?

My query with a result
[Database with Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXRST.png)

My current code    `

```
<?php 
require '../include/db-conn.php';
session_start();

$query = "SELECT YEAR(ddate), treatment, count(*) AS count FROM 
patient_records GROUP BY YEAR(ddate), treatment";

$aresult = $mysqli->query($query);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(){

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)){

    echo " ['Year', '".$row["treatment"]."',],
           ['".$row["YEAR(ddate)"]."', ".$row['count']."],";

 }
?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```

[The result with current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXAmU.png)

Comment: _It still not working..._ What does that exactly mean?

Comment: sry i mean i still not getting what i need

Comment: _..i mean i still not getting what i need..._ Again... what does that mean? What do you need? What is your expected output what is the current behaviour of the code? What errors/issues are you facing?

Comment: Look at the picture (The result with current code) the year below should be only 2016, 2017, 2018 and it has only 1 data it should be exam & cleanings, fluoride treatment and etc. and the lines of the graph is missing